# $_POST doesn't work for PHP post. ISSET reports that no such value was forwared via post method?

Tags: php

I have a form for a comment section. Here every comment has unique IDs.
But however, the comments aren't forwarded to the action PHP form.

Code for comments:

```
    echo '<form action="interact.php" method="post">';
    $new_refreshed_ID = 'uni_story_ID_' . $row['ID'] . '_comment_ID_' . $cache_ready_new_comment_ID;
    echo '<textarea name="' . $new_refreshed_ID . 'rows="12" cols="70"></textarea>';
    echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button>';
    echo '</form>';
$_SESSION['assoc'] = $row['ID'];
$_SESSION['cache_comment_details'] = $new_refreshed_ID;
```

My code for receiving the request:
interact.php:

```
<?php
session_start();


    $assoc = $_SESSION['assoc'];
                $get_comment = $_SESSION['cache_comment_details'];

                if(isset($_POST[$get_comment])) {
                    echo "yea!";
                } else {
                    echo "no!";
                    die();
                }
```

I get no in the interact.php which means that no data was forwarded.
How can this be?

btw comment id's are in this manner (for example):

**uni_story_ID_4_comment_ID_17**

I did check $new_refreshed_ID. It is showing all the values properly as desired. I did start the sessions in the both PHP files.

Comment: With all HTML but especially forms, validate your HTML to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<textarea name="' . $new_refreshed_ID . 'rows="12" cols="70"></textarea>';
```

You need to close the name of textarea like this:

```
echo '<textarea name="' . $new_refreshed_ID . '" rows="12" cols="70"></textarea>';
```

Edit:
Even Better to not use php when not needed (to avoid those) you can maybe do something like this:

```
<textarea name="<?php print $new_refreshed_ID;?>" rows="12" cols="70"></textarea>
```

Please note that this is an Example, i'm only printing what is really needed with php, otherwise i'll stay with html :)

Comment: You can also make a cleaner, easier to read version of the original by using variable interpolation and the right kind of quotes, for example: `echo "<textarea name='$new_refreshed_ID' rows='12' cols='70'></textarea>";` (HTML doesn't really care what kind of quotes you use for its attribute values.)

Comment: @MattGibson It's an idea that too :)